# Image not displayed in ImageView: JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Below is the code I use to view image and caption text together:

```
    try
                    {
                        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( new File("data.txt") );
                        String text = scanner.useDelimiter("ENDOFFILE").next();
                        scanner.close(); // Put this call in a finally block
                        System.out.println(text);
                        String[] data = text.split("\n");
                        for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                        {
                            if(i%2==0)
                            {
                                System.out.println("This is "+data[i]);
                                Image img = new Image(new File(data[i]).toURI().toString(), 100, 0, false, false);
                                ImageView selectedImage = new ImageView();   
                                selectedImage.setImage(img);
                                v.getChildren().addAll(selectedImage);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Text t = new Text(data[i]);
                                t.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 14));
                                v.getChildren().add(t);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception E)
                    {
                        E.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    root2.getChildren().add(v);
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root2, 1000, 1000);
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    stage.show();
}
```

`data[i]` for the image is `Udiagram.jpg` which is present within the same directory as the program. No exceptions occur but the image is not displayed, it shows empty with only text shown as follows: `Text goes here`.

The file `data.txt` is as follows:

```
UDiagram.jpg
Hit and Run
ENDOFFILE
```

What could be the reason for not displaying the image but only the text?

Comment: `new File(...)` will resolve files relative to the *working directory*, over which you have little or no control. (Most IDEs will make the working directory the project directory, though it is configurable, and obviously it will likely be different when the application is deployed and run). If these files are part of the application (i.e. they will be bundled with the jar file), you should load them as resources via the class loader. (The same is true for your `data.txt` file.) You can always print out the URL you create to see what it is trying to load.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to concatenate the file and folder name to the beginning of your String.

```
Image image = new Image("file:FOLDER_NAME/imageName.gif");
ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
imageView.setImage(image);

imageView.setFitWidth(100);
imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
imageView.setSmooth(true);
```